# Adding class to anchor tag inside of repeater in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

aspx file

```
<ul>
                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt1" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <li><a id="a1" href="javascript:void(0);" runat="server">Text</a></li>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><a id="name" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                    <%# Eval("Name").ToString() %></a>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
```

Now there are five items in the ItemTemplate of this repeater..what i want is to set class of each of the anchor tags as "mySprite id1,mySprite id2 , mySprite id3 and so on.."

for that I did this in code behind...

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    Name.Attributes.Add("class", "sprite id" + i);
                }
```

Now when I view page source, ALL my anchor tags have got class set as class="sprite id5"

what am I doing wrong ? Plz help..thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in your `OnItemDataBound` event handler:

```
protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        HtmlAnchor nameAnchor = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("name");
        nameAnchor.Attributes.Add("class", "sprite id" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this..now the class is shown as empty string in all anchor tags in Page's source :(

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the `for` loop, `Name` has the value "id5".  The `for` loop in code behind is evaluated first, then the end result value of "id5" is bound to the repeater (5 times).

Since the `<asp:Repeater>` is designed to display data from a `DataSource`, you could add the class names "id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, etc." to each row of your data, and bind that field to the class name.

Or, unless you are using GUIDs, you can `Concat()` the id field of the table to "id"

Comment: yep I know..that's why asking how to do it :)

Comment: Wow, the expectations *HIGH* for getting fast solutions on this site!

Comment: yes a bit..not sure how to go abt implementing it though..could u plz give an example or something? thnx

Comment: A statistically unique 128-bit number used as an id for database rows as well as other uses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier